# Rhino INSERT SQL statement

Tags: sql, rhino

From Rhino, I am running the following script:

```
var SQLstatement = connection.createStatement();

query =  "INSERT INTO TableName(ID, Name, Date) VALUES   ('1234', 'John Smith', '2012-05-24')";

for (var i = 0; i <= 1500; i++)
    {

    SQLstatement.executeUpdate(query);  
}
```

All what I am trying to do is to insert 1,500 times the values listed in the query above into an SQL table.

However, due to limitations in SQL the statement inserts only 1000 records. Is there a way to insert all 1500 records? I would prefer not to use any text files with the option of bulk insert.

Comment: divide the loop into two, 1:- 0 to 999 and then 1000 to 1500

Comment: What limitations in SQL restrict the number of times that you can call an `insert`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing that should limit you to only 1000 inserts, therefore it sounds like related to a commit. Try the following options:

1. Add a commit at the end
2. Check if there's some kind of setting in Rhino that commits in batches of 1000
3. Try running your code with say 500 and 2500 iterations separately and check how many records get inserted in each case

Comment: The issue was a setting in Rhino and nothing was wrong with the code.

Answer (score 1):

How about a different approach -- just run the `sql` statement once.   This creates a `cartesian product` which creates the 1500 records in a single statement.

```
INSERT INTO TableName(ID, Name, Date) 
SELECT '1234', 'John Smith', '2012-05-24'
FROM (SELECT 1 rn UNION SELECT 2) t, (SELECT 1 rn union SELECT 2) t2,
     (SELECT 1 rn union SELECT 2) t3, (SELECT 1 rn union SELECT 2) t4,
     (SELECT 1 rn union SELECT 2) t5, (SELECT 1 rn union SELECT 2) t6,
     (SELECT 1 rn union SELECT 2) t7, (SELECT 1 rn union SELECT 2) t8,
     (SELECT 1 rn union SELECT 2) t9, (SELECT 1 rn union SELECT 2) t10,
     (SELECT 1 rn union SELECT 2) t11, (SELECT 1 rn union SELECT 2) t12
LIMIT 1500
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7a387/1)

Comment: This is an interesting idea and it works for my example.

Answer (score 0):

Domt know what the problem you are facing so that 1500 records are not insert in single go, but if something there Divide the loop into two, 1:- 0 to 999 and then 1000 to 1500.

(Just sample concept, not actual code)

```
BEGIn TRAN
        for (var i = 0; i <= 999; i++)
        {
           SQLstatement.executeUpdate(query);  
         }

COMMIT
 BEGIn TRAN   
        for (var i = 1000; i <= 1500; i++)
        {
             SQLstatement.executeUpdate(query);  
        }
COMMIT
```

Comment: @benji:- it is breaking the loop so that no more than 1000 records in single loop, and then commit

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure what's happening is that @benji is on the right track. My guess is that your database implementation buffers records without committing unless the buffer reaches 1,000; then it commits. Your first 1,000 go in when the 1,000th is run (or maybe the 1,001st), but the remainder never get committed.

So the answer here is in parts of the implementation not provided. This has nothing to do with Rhino or SQL. It also means the other suggestions (like just insert 1,000 at a time) won't work either, because the driver is never going to commit the second batch in those cases, and will commit the first by coincidence.

Post more information about database driver, connection, etc. and we may be able to help you.

Or for a more shot-in-the-dark version, try adding connection.commit() at the end of the program (I am making some assumptions about what `connection` is, so this may not work).

Comment: I've tried the connection.commit() but it did not work. It turned out it was a setting in Rhino as I mentioned above. Thanks for the advice

Comment: What "Rhino" do you mean? The Rhino JavaScript engine? Or something else?